# Convergence almost everywhere and convergence in measure

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{L},m)$, let $f_{n}(x)=n\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$ then the sequence converges to $0$ everywhere except at $x=0$ thus $f_{n}$ converges a.e.

Then in my book (Folland) we have that if $f_{n}\to f$ a.e and $|f_{n}|\le g\in L^{1}$ then $f_{n}\to f$ in $L^{1}$ too. The above conditions are met.

Finally by another proposition we have that if $f_{n}\to f$ in $L^{1}$ then $f_{n}\to f$ in measure.

I wonder if these relations holds for both finite and infinite measurable spaces?

Comment: Yes they do, $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B, \lambda)$ is an infinite (though $\sigma$-finite) Measure space satisfying this.

Comment: @AlexR: of course, I missed $m(\mathbb{R})=\infty$ ;) thank you

Comment: nvm. Want me to post this as an answer so this gets marked as solved?

Comment: @AlexR: yes please, there is nothing more to add here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works always, for example $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B, \lambda)$ forms a $\sigma$-finite but infinite measure space on which this works.

Answer (score 1):

It actually work in *any* measure space as a consequence of the inequality 
$$\mu\{|f_n-f|\gt\varepsilon\}\leqslant \varepsilon\lVert f_n-f\rVert_{L^1}.$$

Since the $f_n$ have a $\sigma$-finite support, we can assume we work on a $\sigma$-finite space, even if it's not needed.

Comment: @DavidGiraudo: I have question: $f_{n}\to f$ in $L^{1}$ if $\displaystyle\int_{X}|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|d\mu\to 0$ right? but for $f_{n}(x)=n\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$ we have $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}n\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}dm=1\not\to 0$

Comment: Your example shows that convergence in measure does not imply convergence in $L^1$.

Comment: I was rather referring to the above statements in my post. Since $f_{n}\to f$ a.e then by above shouldn't we have that it converges in $L^1$ too?

Comment: No, because we don't have _dominated_ convergence with your choice of $f_n$.

Comment: yes, you are right, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!